# rvest: Scraping table from webpage

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to retrieve the following table:

[image]

to be found on [this website.](https://www.wettportal.com/Fussball/Champions_League/Champions_League/Paris_Saint-Germain_-_Real_Madrid_2448367.html)

I managed to retrieve the quotes using the following code:

```
library('rvest')
url.2 <- "https://www.wettportal.com/Fussball/Champions_League/Champions_League/Paris_Saint-Germain_-_Real_Madrid_2448367.html"
webpage.2 <- read_html(url.2)
oddscell.html <- html_nodes(webpage.2, ".oddscell")
oddscell.data <- html_text(oddscell.html)
home <- oddscell.data[seq(1, length(oddscell.data), 3)]
draw <- oddscell.data[seq(2, length(oddscell.data), 3)]
away <- oddscell.data[seq(3, length(oddscell.data), 3)]

my.quotes <- cbind(home, draw, away)
```

With the following result (only the first 3 rows):

```
  my.quotes[1:3,]
  home                     draw                    away                   
 [1,] "1.67"                   "4.25"                  "4.35"                 
 [2,] "1.68"                   "4.10"                  "4.20"                 
 [3,] "1.72"                   "4.70"                  "4.56"
```

I managed to do something similar to retrieve the name of the bookies using `html_nodes(webpage.2, ".bookie")`.

My question is: Is there a way to scrape the table all at once?

Comment: Like `html_table(html_nodes(webpage.2, ".table-type-odds-1"))` ?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Precisely what I was seeking, vielen Dank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site is blocked for me!  I can't see anything there, but I can tell you, basically, it should be done like this.

The html_nodes() function turns each HTML tag into a row in an R dataframe.

```
library(rvest)

## Loading required package: xml2

# Define the url once.
URL <- "https://scistarter.com/finder?phrase=&lat=&lng=&activity=At%20the%20beach&topic=&search_filters=&search_audience=&page=1#view-projects"

    scistarter_html <- read_html(URL)
    scistarter_html

## {xml_document}
## <html class="no-js" lang="en">
## [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset= ...
## [2] <body>\n    \n    \n    <svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; he ...
```

We’re able to retrieve the same HTML code we saw in our browser. This is not useful yet, but it does show that we’re able to retrieve the same HTML code we saw in our browser. Now we will begin filtering through the HTML to find the data we’re after.

The data we want are stored in a table, which we can tell by looking at the “Inspect Element” window.

This grabs all the nodes that have links in them.

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <a href="/index.html" class="site-header__branding" title="go to the ...
## [2] <a href="/dashboard">My Account</a>
## [3] <a href="/finder" class="is-active">Project Finder</a>
## [4] <a href="/events">Event Finder</a>
## [5] <a href="/people-finder">People Finder</a>
## [6] <a href="#dialog-login" rel="modal:open">log in</a>
```

In a more complex example, we could use this to “crawl” the page, but that’s for another day.

Every div on the page:

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <div class="site-header__nav js-hamburger b-utility">\n        <butt ...
## [2] <div class="site-header__nav__body js-hamburger__body">\n          < ...
## [3] <div class="nav-tools">\n            <div class="nav-tools__search"> ...
## [4] <div class="nav-tools__search">\n              <div class="field">\n ...
## [5] <div class="field">\n                <form method="get" action="/fin ...
## [6] <div class="input-group input-group--flush">\n                    <d ...
```

… the nav-tools div. This calls by css where class=nav-tools.

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div.nav-tools") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <div class="nav-tools">\n            <div class="nav-tools__search"> ...
```

We can call the nodes by id as follows.

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div#project-listing") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <div id="project-listing" class="subtabContent">\n          \n       ...
```

All the tables as follows:

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [2] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [3] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [4] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [5] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [6] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
```

See the (related) link below, for more info.

https://rpubs.com/Radcliffe/superbowl